# Como saber a quantidade de vezes que um objeto apareceu no array

Tags: javascript, array

Gostaria de saber como faço pra retornar a quantidade de vezes que cada objeto apareceu em um array, por exemplo:

Entrada:

```
array1 = [
  {nome: joao},
  {nome: maria},
  {nome: joao},
  {nome: carlos},
  {nome: joao},
  {nome: carlos},
]
```

Saída:

```
array2 = [
  {nome: joao, quantidade: 3},
  {nome: maria, quantidade: 1},
  {nome: carlos, quantidade: 2}
]
```

Meu código:

```
for(var h in array1){
  array3.push({
    [array1[h].nome]: false
  })
}
for(var i in array1){
  var count = 1
  var nome = array1[i].nome
  for(var k in array3){
     if(array3[k][nome]==false){
        for(var j=i+1; j<array1.length; j++){
          if(array1[i].nome==array1[j].nome){
            count++
            total+=count
            array3[k][nome] = true
          }         
        }
        array2.push({
          nome: nome,
          quantidade: count
        })
        break
      }
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podemos criar uma função que aceita dois argumentos:

- O `array` de objetos;
- A propriedade que usaremos para realizar a contagem.

Algo assim:

```js
function countObjects(input, prop) {
  // Criamos um objeto que vai armazenar o número de cada objeto.
  const counter = {}

  for (const obj of input) {
    // Nome da iteração atual:
    const name = obj[prop]

    if (counter.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      // Caso o nome já exista no contador, incremente o número em 1.
      counter[name]++
    } else {
      // Caso contrário, inicialize em 1.
      counter[name] = 1
    }
  }

  return Object.entries(counter).map(([key, value]) => ({
    [prop]: key,
    quantidade: value
  }))
}
```

Executando na prática:

```js
const array = [
  { nome: 'joao' },
  { nome: 'maria' },
  { nome: 'joao' },
  { nome: 'carlos' },
  { nome: 'joao' },
  { nome: 'carlos' }
]

function countObjects(input, prop) {
  // Criamos um objeto que vai armazenar o número de cada objeto.
  const counter = {}

  for (const obj of input) {
    // Nome da iteração atual:
    const name = obj[prop]

    if (counter.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      // Caso o nome já exista no contador, incremente o número em 1.
      counter[name]++
    } else {
      // Caso contrário, inicialize em 1.
      counter[name] = 1
    }
  }

  return Object.entries(counter).map(([key, value]) => ({
    [prop]: key,
    quantidade: value
  }))
}

// Irá verificar quantos objetos existem, contando a proriedade "nome":
const output = countObjects(array, 'nome')

// Mostra o output:
console.log(output)
```

## Referência de recursos utilizados no código:

- [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty);
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries);
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

---

**Bônus**: *Rewrite* maluco usando [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Daniel' },
  { name: 'Louis' },
  { name: 'Alice' },
  { name: 'Louis' },
  { name: 'Alice' },
  { name: 'Petter' },
  { name: 'Louis' }
]

function countObjects(input, prop) {
  return Object.entries(
    input.reduce(
      (a, c) => ({
        ...a,
        [c[prop]]: a.hasOwnProperty(c[prop]) ? ++a[c[prop]] : 1
      }),
      {}
    )
  ).map(([key, count]) => ({
    [prop]: key,
    count
  }))
}

console.log(countObjects(data, 'name'))
```

Comment: Excelente resposta, eu sempre procuro responder de maneia mais simples possível, pois, não sei ao certo o conhecimento sobre o assunto de quem fez a pergunta, mas, a sua resposta demonstra um grande conhecimento na linguagem. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Pode chegar ao resultado esperado utilizando o método [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro):

```js
let array1 = [
  {nome: 'joao'},
  {nome: 'maria'},
  {nome: 'joao'},
  {nome: 'carlos'},
  {nome: 'joao'},
  {nome: 'carlos'},
];

let nomeJoao = array1.filter(function(elemento, index) {
  let joao = elemento.nome == 'joao';
  return joao;
})

let nomeMaria = array1.filter(function(elemento) {
  let maria = elemento.nome == 'maria';
  return maria;
})

let nomeCarlos = array1.filter(function(elemento) {
  let carlos = elemento.nome == 'carlos';
  return carlos;
})

let array2 = [
  {nome: nomeJoao[0].nome, quantidade: nomeJoao.length},
  {nome: nomeMaria[0].nome, quantidade: nomeMaria.length},
  {nome: nomeCarlos[0].nome, quantidade: nomeCarlos.length}
]

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Como eu poderia deixar dinâmico, porque a lista de nomes pode aparecer novos nomes. Tentei aqui e ele consegue retornar os valores mas retorna por exemplo: joao: 3, joao:2 e joao:1, porque o for nao ta conseguindo pular pro proximo caso ele ja tenha contado joao. Como faço isso com o filter

Comment: Editei a resposta, basicamente você irá chamar a variável que contém o filter passando o **.nome** para sempre pegar o nome relacionado com a quantidade.