# Como contar objetos de forma mais limpa?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para contar os objetos iguais e retornar um array com as respectivas quantidades de vezes que ele apareceu.

Estou usando vários "for" para fazer isso, e não sei fazer com os métodos "map, reduce"

Por exemplo:

Entrada:

```
array1 = [
  {nome: joao, sobrenome: silva},
  {nome: claudio, sobrenome: silva},
  {nome: jose, sobrenome: oliveira},
  {nome: joao, sobrenome: costa},
  {nome: joao, sobrenome: silva}
]
```

Saída:

```
array2 = [
  {nome: joao, sobrenome: silva, quantidade: 2},
  {nome: joao, sobrenome: costa, quantidade: 1},
  {nome: claudio, sobrenome: silva, quantidade: 1},
  {nome: jose, sobrenome: oliveira, quantidade: 1}
]
```

Comment: A forma mais simples de se fazer é usando `for`. Não há por que criar uma complexidade adicional usando reduce. Você pode ver algo parecido nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/377208/69296). Aliás, a notação do seu exemplo está errada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por passos, conceptualmente, poderia ser:

- cria uma array paralela para ir incluíndo os contadores
- percorre cada objeto para os testar e adicionar ao contador

Na prática isso poderia ser feito assim:

```js
const array1 = [
  {nome: 'joao', sobrenome: 'silva'},
  {nome: 'claudio', sobrenome: 'silva'},
  {nome: 'jose', sobrenome: 'oliveira'},
  {nome: 'joao', sobrenome: 'costa'},
  {nome: 'joao', sobrenome: 'silva'}
];

const contador = array1.reduce((obj, el) => {
  const signature = JSON.stringify(el);
  if (!obj[signature]){
    obj[signature] = {...el, quantidade: 0};
  }
  obj[signature].quantidade ++;
  return obj;
}, {});
const contados = Object.values(contador);

console.log(contados);
```

Comment: Sergio, voce pode me ajudar a entender o que esta acontecendo dentro da condiçao "if"?